# Connecting SQL server 2014 database with android application

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database, android-studio

I have created a database with SQL server 2014, and i want to connect and access it from android application im developing in android studio.

is it possible without creating a web service?

Comment: Have a look: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170463/why-to-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-access-to-a-relational-database-for-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever do any heavy weighted operations such as directly connecting to an sql server since consumes heavy battery and it requires huge data consumption where the end users might not prefer.So The only light weighted way present is to use your own TCP based logic layer i.e  giving a call to web services.

You can refer to KSOAP2 library in connecting to your webservice which gives you a response to the request you make.If you are a programmer of .net you can write an asmx web service.And connecting to to the web service is given clearly in this link [Connecting to ASMX Web Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap)

Comment: I already did this for some operations, but i don't know i feel it easier if i did directly in android. but it seems to be bad practice. so yeah, i will continue with web services, THANK YOU!